# Overfull message not yet clarified

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I have found a shift in the left margin of my document signalled by the error message

```
Overfull \hbox (12.87598pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 56--57
```

The following is an extract from my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers} % for immediate answers (not stored in a file)
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremindent40pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemme}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}
\newtheorem{proof}{Démonstration}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{double, shorten <=12pt}
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{proposition}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{double, shorten <=12pt}
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{decoration={zigzag,amplitude=2pt,pre=moveto,pre length=12pt},decorate}
    }
\newtheorem{Exc}{Exercice}
\Newassociation{correction}{Soln}{mycor}
\Newassociation{indication}{Indi}{myind}
%\newcommand{\precorrection}{~{\bf \footnotesize [Exercice corrig\'e]}}
%\newcommand{\preindication}{~{\bf \footnotesize [Indication]}}
\renewcommand{\Solnlabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Correction #1}}
\renewcommand{\Indilabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Indication #1}}
\def\exo#1{\futurelet\testchar\MaybeOptArgmyexoo}
\def\MaybeOptArgmyexoo{\ifx[\testchar \let\next\OptArgmyexoo
                        \else \let\next\NoOptArgmyexoo \fi \next}
\def\OptArgmyexoo[#1]{\begin{exo}[#1]\normalfont}
\def\NoOptArgmyexoo{\begin{exo}\normalfont}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\end{exo}}
\newcommand{\flag}[1]{}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\def\Tiny{\fontsize{4pt}{4pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\eqdef}{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\Tiny def}}}{=}}}
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{mycor}[ficcorex]
 \Opensolutionfile{myind}[ficind]


\begin{exo}
La différence symétrique de deux ensembles $A$ et $B$ est définie par
\[
A\Delta B \eqdef  (A \cup B)\setminus (A \cup B):
\]

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Soient $A \in \mathbb{N}^{prime}$ et $B \in  \mathbb{N}.$ On définit
\[
d(A:B) \coloneq
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\min(A \Delta B)} & \text{si} \, A \neq B \\
0 & \text{si} \, A=B.
\end{cases}
\]
Démontrer que si $A, B, C$ sont trois ensembles distincts de $\mathbb N^{\star},$ alors
\[
d(A,B) \leqslant   \max\left(d(A,C), d(C,B)\right)
\]

  \item Conclure que $d$ définit une distance sur $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N^{\ast}).$
  \item  Montrer que pour tout $n \in  N^{\ast}$ et tous $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}^{\ast},$
\[
d(A B) < \dfrac{1}{n} \Longleftrightarrow  A\cap [1,n]=B\cap [1,n].
\]
  \item  On considère la suite $(X_n)$ dans $\mathcal P(\mathbb N^{\ast}),$ où
  \[
X_n = \{1,2^n, 3^n, \cdots \}
\]
(Noter que $X_1 = \{1, 2, 3, \cdots \}, X_2 = \{1, 4, 8 \cdots \}$ est l'ensemble des carrés, $X_3 =
\{1, 9, 27, \cdots \}$ est l'ensemble des cubes). Montrer que la suite $(X_n)$ converge vers
un ensemble $X \in \mathcal  P(\mathbb N)$ que l'on déterminera. (Indication : utiliser le résultat de la
question précédente).
\end{enumerate}
\end{exo}
 \begin{indication}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Indication : on pourra utiliser l'inclusion $A\Delta B \subset (A\Delta C) \cup (C\Delta B).$
\end{enumerate}
\end{indication}

 \begin{correction}
 Commençons par montrer l'inclusion $A \Delta B \subset (A\Delta C) \cup  (C\Delta B)$ (même si
l'énoncé permettait de l'utiliser sans la démontrer). Soit $x  \in  A\Delta B = (A \setminus B) \cup  (B \setminus A).$
Supposons que $x \in  A \setminus B$ (l'autre cas étant symétrique). Si $x \in  C,$  on a $x \in  C \setminus B,$  et donc
$x \in  C\Delta B.$  Si $x \neq  C,$  on a $x \in  A \setminus C,$  et donc $x \in  A\Delta C.$  Dans les deux cas on obtient bien
$x \in  (A\Delta C) \cup  (C\Delta B),$  ce qu'on voulait.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Montrons maintenant l'inégalité
\[
d(A,B) \leqslant  max{d(A,C), d(C,B)}
\]
De l'inclusion $A\Delta B \subset (A\Delta C) \cup (C\Delta B)$ on déduit l'inégalité
\[
\min(A\Delta B) \geqslant \min(\min(A\Delta C), \min(C\Delta B)).
\]
En passant à l'inverse on obtient $\dfrac{1}{\min(A4B)}  \leqslant \max \left( \dfrac{1}{\min(A \Delta C)} , \min(C\Delta B)\right).$
\item  L'équivalence $d(A,B) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow  A = B$ découle immédiatement de la définition, de même
que l'égalité $d(A,B) = d(B,A).$  Enfin, l'inégalité triangulaire est une conséquence
de l'inégalité ultramétrique (c'est-à-dire l'inégalité démontrée dans la question précédente).
Ainsi $d$ définit une distance sur $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}^{\ast}).$
\item Si $A = B$ les deux côtés de l'équivalence sont clairement vraie. Supposons donc $A \neq  B.$
Par définition on a
\[
d(A,B) < \dfrac{1}{n} \Longleftrightarrow \min(A \Delta B) > n.
\]
Or $\min(A\Delta B) > n$ signifie que tout entier $p \leqslant  n$ ou bien appartient à la fois à $A$ et à
$B$, ou bien n'appartient à aucun des deux. On a donc
\[
\min(A\Delta B) > n \Longleftrightarrow A \cap [1, n] = B \cap [1, n].
\]  
\item Montrons que la suite $(X_n),$ où $X_n = {1, 2^n, 3^n, \cdots },$ converge vers le singleton $X =\{1\}.$ Si $n \in  \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ est fixé,
et que $p > n$, on a $X_p \cap [1, 2^n] = \{1\}$ (car $2^p > 2^n$), et donc par
la question précédente $d(X,X_p) <\dfrac{ 1}{2^n }.$ Ainsi $d(X,X_p) \to  0$ quand $p \to \infty.$
\end{enumerate}
 \end{correction} 
 \end{document}
```

Can any one kind soul explain this problem to us?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: I get an error message saying that `\eqdef` is not defined. What am I doing wrong? Also the culprit seems to be the equation/expression just before item 2 on the second page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a shift in the left margin of my document".  Ignoring all the error messages that your code throws up (eg., `\eqdef` not being defined) and plowing on, it turns out that there are *three* `Overfull \hbox` instances in the test document. What these warning (not "error") messages tell you is that LaTeX couldn't find line breaks that obey the right-hand margin of the text block; put differently, the material protrudes into the right-hand margin -- very severely so in the third instance. The best way to fix this is to re-write the passages in question.

Comment: Thak you for remarks. make correction about \eqdef

Comment: I get another error: `! LaTeX Error: \begin{Exc} on input line 69 ended by \end{document}.` Do you check the code by running it before uploading it here?

Comment: I fixed a correction. I wish it would be all right.

Comment: the posted code produces fatal error and no output at all and no overfull box message, I get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\begin ...1\endcsname }}\@ignorefalse \begingroup 
                                                  \@endpefalse \reserved@a 
l.70 La
        différence symétrique de deux ensembles $A$ et $B$ est définie par
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the environment `exo` looks too complicated to me. As far as I can see it defines only an environment with one optional argument which uses `\normalfont`:

```
\newenvironment{exo}[1][]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
```

With the global document class option `draft`  you can mark all overfull boxes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers} % for immediate answers (not stored in a file)
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremindent=40pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemme}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}
\newtheorem{proof}{Démonstration}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{double, shorten <=12pt}
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{proposition}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{double, shorten <=12pt}
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{decoration={zigzag,amplitude=2pt,pre=moveto,pre length=12pt},decorate}
    }
\newtheorem{Exc}{Exercice}
\Newassociation{correction}{Soln}{mycor}
\Newassociation{indication}{Indi}{myind}
%\newcommand{\precorrection}{~{\bf \footnotesize [Exercice corrig\'e]}}
%\newcommand{\preindication}{~{\bf \footnotesize [Indication]}}
\renewcommand{\Solnlabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Correction #1}}
\renewcommand{\Indilabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Indication #1}}
\newenvironment{exo}[1][]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
\newcommand{\flag}[1]{}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\def\Tiny{\fontsize{4pt}{4pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\eqdef}{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\Tiny def}}}{=}}}
\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{mycor}[ficcorex]
\Opensolutionfile{myind}[ficind]


\begin{exo}
La différence symétrique de deux ensembles $A$ et $B$ est définie par
\[
A\Delta B \eqdef  (A \cup B)\setminus (A \cup B):
\]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Soient $A \in \mathbb{N}^{prime}$ et $B \in  \mathbb{N}.$ On définit
\[
d(A:B) \coloneq
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\min(A \Delta B)} & \text{si} \, A \neq B \\
0 & \text{si} \, A=B.
\end{cases}
\]
Démontrer que si $A, B, C$ sont trois ensembles distincts de $\mathbb N^{\star},$ alors
\[
d(A,B) \leqslant   \max\left(d(A,C), d(C,B)\right)
\]
  \item Conclure que $d$ définit une distance sur $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N^{\ast}).$
  \item  Montrer que pour tout $n \in  N^{\ast}$ et tous $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}^{\ast},$
\[
d(A B) < \dfrac{1}{n} \Longleftrightarrow  A\cap [1,n]=B\cap [1,n].
\]
  \item  On considère la suite $(X_n)$ dans $\mathcal P(\mathbb N^{\ast}),$ où
  \[
X_n = \{1,2^n, 3^n, \cdots \}
\]
(Noter que $X_1 = \{1, 2, 3, \cdots \}, X_2 = \{1, 4, 8 \cdots \}$ est l'ensemble des carrés, $X_3 =
\{1, 9, 27, \cdots \}$ est l'ensemble des cubes). Montrer que la suite $(X_n)$ converge vers
un ensemble $X \in \mathcal  P(\mathbb N)$ que l'on déterminera. (Indication : utiliser le résultat de la
question précédente).
\end{enumerate}
\end{exo}

 \begin{indication}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Indication : on pourra utiliser l'inclusion $A\Delta B \subset (A\Delta C) \cup (C\Delta B).$
\end{enumerate}
\end{indication}

 \begin{correction}
 Commençons par montrer l'inclusion $A \Delta B \subset (A\Delta C) \cup  (C\Delta B)$ (même si
l'énoncé permettait de l'utiliser sans la démontrer). Soit $x  \in  A\Delta B = (A \setminus B) \cup  (B 
\setminus A).$
Supposons que $x \in  A \setminus B$ (l'autre cas étant symétrique). Si $x \in  C,$  on a $x \in  C \setminus 
B,$  et donc
$x \in  C\Delta B.$  Si $x \neq  C,$  on a $x \in  A \setminus C,$  et donc $x \in  A\Delta C.$  Dans les 
deux cas on obtient bien
$x \in  (A\Delta C) \cup  (C\Delta B),$  ce qu'on voulait.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Montrons maintenant l'inégalité
\[
d(A,B) \leqslant  max{d(A,C), d(C,B)}
\]
De l'inclusion $A\Delta B \subset (A\Delta C) \cup (C\Delta B)$ on déduit l'inégalité
\[
\min(A\Delta B) \geqslant \min(\min(A\Delta C), \min(C\Delta B)).
\]
En passant à l'inverse on obtient $\dfrac{1}{\min(A4B)}  \leqslant \max \left( \dfrac{1}{\min(A \Delta C)} , 
\min(C\Delta B)\right).$
\item  L'équivalence $d(A,B) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow  A = B$ découle immédiatement de la définition, de même
que l'égalité $d(A,B) = d(B,A).$  Enfin, l'inégalité triangulaire est une conséquence
de l'inégalité ultramétrique (c'est-à-dire l'inégalité démontrée dans la question précédente).
Ainsi $d$ définit une distance sur $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}^{\ast}).$
\item Si $A = B$ les deux côtés de l'équivalence sont clairement vraie. Supposons donc $A \neq  B.$
Par définition on a
\[
d(A,B) < \dfrac{1}{n} \Longleftrightarrow \min(A \Delta B) > n.
\]
Or $\min(A\Delta B) > n$ signifie que tout entier $p \leqslant  n$ ou bien appartient à la fois à $A$ et à
$B$, ou bien n'appartient à aucun des deux. On a donc
\[
\min(A\Delta B) > n \Longleftrightarrow A \cap [1, n] = B \cap [1, n].
\]  
\item Montrons que la suite $(X_n),$ où $X_n = {1, 2^n, 3^n, \cdots },$ converge vers le singleton $X 
=\{1\}.$ Si $n \in  \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ est fixé,
et que $p > n$, on a $X_p \cap [1, 2^n] = \{1\}$ (car $2^p > 2^n$), et donc par
la question précédente $d(X,X_p) <\dfrac{ 1}{2^n }.$ Ainsi $d(X,X_p) \to  0$ quand $p \to \infty.$
\end{enumerate}
 \end{correction} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please be graciously kind enough to correct the error given by this message:                                                                       ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\begin ...1\endcsname }}\@ignorefalse \begingroup 
                                                  \@endpefalse \reserved@a 
l.19 La
        différence symétrique de deux ensembles $A$ et $B$ est définie par
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Comment: This error is not in my example! It is your definition of  `exo`, there is a recursion.

Comment: If the displayed example is indeed an accurate result from your intended code, all the overfull boxes occur with math expressions.  In the second case, the obvious fix (which would be recommended by the copyeditors at the American Math Society) is to display the math with `\[ ... \]`.  The first instance can be handled in the same way, but it would also be possible to break the line after the heading; even with a paragraph or item indentation, the entire new line will fit within the margins.