# Remove the small black rectangle that appears at the end of environment

Tags: environments

I would like to correct the attached script that I was lucky enough to have it thanks to this  [Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494251/overfull-message-not-yet-clarified)

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers} % for immediate answers (not stored in a file)
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremindent=40pt
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
\newtheorem{proof}{Démonstration}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{double, shorten <=12pt}
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{proposition}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{double, shorten <=12pt}
    }
\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{decoration={zigzag,amplitude=2pt,pre=moveto,pre length=12pt},decorate}
    }
\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}
\Newassociation{correction}{Soln}{mycor}
\Newassociation{indication}{Indi}{myind}
\renewcommand{\Solnlabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Correction #1}}
\renewcommand{\Indilabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Indication #1}}
\newcommand{\flag}[1]{}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\def\Tiny{\fontsize{4pt}{4pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\eqdef}{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\Tiny def}}}{=}}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textsf{\Large
     Exercices                                  % TITRE
}}
\end{center}
\hrule
\vspace*{1cm}
\Opensolutionfile{mycor}[ficcorex]
\Opensolutionfile{myind}[ficind]

\begin{exo}
Soient $(X,d)$ un espace métrique et $A\subset X$, $A\neq\emptyset$. On pose:
 \[
 d(x, A)=\inf\{ d(x,a)\ ;\, a\in A\}.
 \]
 Qu'on appelle la \textit{ distance du point $x$ à l'ensemble $A$}.
 On remarque que $d(x, A)$ est bien définie et $\geqslant 0$. De plus, $d(x,A)=0$ si $x\in A$.
 Montrer que
\begin{enumerate}
 \item $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ est $1$-lipschitzienne.
 \item $d(x,A)=d(x,\overline A)$.
 \item $d(x, A)=0\Longleftrightarrow  x\in \overline A$.
 \end{enumerate}
\end{exo}
\begin{correction}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Soient $x, y\in A$. Pour tout $a\in A$ on a
 \[
 -d(x,y)+d(y,a)\leqslant d(x,a)\leqslant d(y,a)+d(x,y).
 \] Par passage à l'inf, on trouve
 $-d(x,y)+d(y, A)\leqslant d(x,A)\leqslant d(y,A)+d(x,y)$, d'où $|d(x, A)-d(y,A)|\leqslant d(x,y)$.
 \item  Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. En particulier, $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$. Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que $d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle que $a_n\to b$. Comme $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ est continue sur $X$, on trouve $d(x, a_n)\to d(x,b)$. Il existe donc un $n_0$ tel que $d(a_{n_0},b)<\varepsilon/2$. Il s'ensuit que
 $$d(x, A)\leqslant d(x, a_{n_0})\leqslant d(x,b)+d(b, a_{n_0})<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon.$$
 $\varepsilon$ étant arbitraire, on trouve $d(x, A)\leqslant d(x,\overline A)$.\\
 \item "$\Longrightarrow$" Si $d(x, A)=0$, alors pour tout $\varepsilon>0$ il existe un $a\in A$ tel que $d(x,a)<\varepsilon$. Pour $\varepsilon=1/(n+1)$, on trouve une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle que $d(x,a_n)<1/(n+1)$. On a donc $a_n\to x$, et par conséquent $x\in\overline A$.\\
  Si $x\in\overline A$, alors $0=d(x,\overline A)=d(x,A)$.
\end{enumerate}
 \end{correction}
\end{document}
```

Here is an error message

```
Overfull \hbox (6.10593pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 87--88
```

[image: Picture]

How to remove the small black rectangle that appears at the end of the correction?

Comment: Remove `draft`, i.e. replace `\documentclass[11pt,draft]{book}` by `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`. These boxed indicate overfull hboxes. Of course, the cleaner way is to shuffle things such that there is no such hbox.

Comment: Note that what you're reporting is not an error message but a warning message.

Comment: Is warning you that there are not a good point to break the line. Before of the math mode is really bad, and before ≥ is also very bad, although LaTeX could be more more tolerant here (It accept a suggestion of  `\linebreak[1]` here, whilst before of `$d(x, ..`.  will accept only the  `\linebreak[4]`) so it break after that. However, for humans probably is better do not break the mathematical expression (in spite of the huge spaces), or better, as suggested, rewrite the paragraph (some like  " ..., et particulièrement, $d(x...."

Comment: Avoid `$$`. In order to solve the particular problem, rewording seems the best approach: remove “Clairement”, that adds nothing. I'd also avoid the whole correction consisting of an `enumerate` environment, that gives an unbalanced look to the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such problems should be tackled when the text is in final form.

The black box, together with the warning about `Overfull \hbox`, signals that TeX was unable to find a suitable break point. There are several actions that can be tried.

My first advice is to avoid an entire `correction` to consist of an `enumerate` environment, which gives an unbalanced look to the page. Another general advice is to load the `microtype` package (although in this case it doesn't help).

In your case, a 6pt overfull means that the `\geqslant` symbol is almost completely in the margin, so this *should* be fixed.

In the code that follows, I show the original, then some possible fixes. In the first fix I keep `enumerate` and push the `\geqslant` symbol to the next line: in a real emergency, this might do, once in a document. The best fix, in any case, is to just omit “Clairement”.

Note the `\thickmuskip` trick where I just add some shrinkability to it: again, once in a document, a reduced space around a relation symbol is not so bad. Don't do a global setting: this could have a very bad impact on formula spacing.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,draft,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Original within \texttt{enumerate}}

\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. 
En particulier,
%%%% the problem!
$d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$.
%%%%
Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que 
$d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle 
que $a_n\to b$. Comme $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ est continue sur $X$, on trouve $d(x, a_n)\to d(x,b)$. 
Il existe donc un $n_0$ tel que $d(a_{n_0},b)<\varepsilon/2$.
\end{enumerate}

\subsubsection*{Original with \texttt{\char`\\linebreak}}

\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. 
En particulier,
%%%% the problem!
$d(x, A)\linebreak[0]\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$.
%%%%
Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que 
$d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle 
que $a_n\to b$. Comme $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ est continue sur $X$, on trouve $d(x, a_n)\to d(x,b)$. 
Il existe donc un $n_0$ tel que $d(a_{n_0},b)<\varepsilon/2$.
\end{enumerate}

\subsubsection*{Without \texttt{enumerate}}

2. Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. 
En particulier,
%%%% the problem!
$d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$.
%%%%
Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que 
$d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle 
que $a_n\to b$. Comme $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ est continue sur $X$, on trouve $d(x, a_n)\to d(x,b)$. 
Il existe donc un $n_0$ tel que $d(a_{n_0},b)<\varepsilon/2$.

\subsubsection*{Locally reduce \texttt{\char`\\thickmuskip}}

2. Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. 
En particulier,
%%%% the problem!
$\thickmuskip=\muexpr\thickmuskip + 0mu plus 0mu minus 2mu\relax 
d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$.
%%%%
Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que 
$d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle 
que $a_n\to b$. Comme $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ est continue sur $X$, on trouve $d(x, a_n)\to d(x,b)$. 
Il existe donc un $n_0$ tel que $d(a_{n_0},b)<\varepsilon/2$.

\subsubsection*{Rewording}

2. Si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. 
En particulier,
%%%% the problem!
$d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$.
%%%%
Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que 
$d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle 
que $a_n\to b$. Comme $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ est continue sur $X$, on trouve $d(x, a_n)\to d(x,b)$. 
Il existe donc un $n_0$ tel que $d(a_{n_0},b)<\varepsilon/2$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your precious advice.

Answer (score 8):

The title of your posting is a bit misleading: the black rectangle -- it's called a "slug" in typography -- occurs at the end of an overfull line, *not* at the end of an environment. The slugs are being inserted because you specified the `draft` document class option.

- The worst way to get rid of the slugs is to remove the `draft` document class option. While it gets rid of the slugs, it does nothing to fix the issues that cause the occurrence of overfull lines.
- The best way to get rid of a slug is to rewrite parts or all of the paragraph in question, so that LaTeX can find other, better line breaks.
- If rephrasing sentences and paragraphs isn't an option, I suggest you change the value of `\thickmuskip` -- a parameter that governs how much whitespace is inserted to the left and right of "relational" operators such as `\subset` and `\geqslant`. The default value of `\thickmuskip` is `5mu`; setting it to `3mu` gets rid of the overfull line and hence gets rid of the slug.

The following is a much-simplified version of your code, to allow us to focus on just the enumerated item where the slug occurs. I suggest that if you're choose the reduce the value of `\thickmuskip`, you reduce the value of `\medmuskip` (which governs the spacing around binary operators) as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers} % for immediate answers (not stored in a file)

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremindent=40pt
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\Newassociation{correction}{Soln}{mycor}
\renewcommand{\Solnlabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Correction #1}}
\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{center}% TITRE
\textbf{\textsf{\Large Exercices}}
\end{center}
\hrule
\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{correction}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Soient $x, y\in A$. Pour tout $a\in A$ on a \dots

\item  Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. En particulier, $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$. Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que $d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle que $a_n\to b$. \dots

\item \begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
\thickmuskip=3mu % default value: 5mu
\medmuskip=3mu   % default value: 4mu
Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. En particulier, $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$. Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que $d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle que $a_n\to b$. \dots 
\endgroup

\item  Clairement, si $A\subset B$, alors $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x, B)$. En particulier, $d(x, A)\geqslant d(x,\overline A)$. Soit $\varepsilon>0$. Il existe un $b\in\overline A$ tel que $d(x,b)<d(x,\overline A)+\varepsilon/2$. Il existe une suite $(a_n)\subset A$ telle que $a_n\to b$. \dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{correction}
\end{document}
```